# Java error while retrieving twitter data using apache flume on centos

Tags: java, apache, flume

I am new to this concept please help me if i am doing something wrong.

I configure multinode hadoop cluster with 4 slaves and one master. Hadoop version is 1.2.1 .

Now i need to configure apache flume into it in order to fetch twitter data.

The following configurations are done in the Flume

In `flume-env.sh`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/
```

and also i configured a `flume.conf` file according to that

I am trying to run flume by command `./flume-ng agent -n MyTwitAgent -c conf -f /opt/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf`

The error is:

```
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64//bin/java -Xmx20m -cp 'conf:/opt/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application -n MyTwitAgent -f /opt/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: I don't see an error, except the fact that flume is complaining about log4j configuration settings.

Comment: I cant get what exactly i am doing wrong. Please some budy help me or please tell me how to retrieve twitter data without using flume in centos

Comment: if you want to get the twitter tweets to hdfs using flume refer the below link : http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html